# certificate from Let's Encrypt fails to renew

Tags: nginx, https, lets-encrypt

I've after much trial and error finally managed to get HTTPS on my site. But the Let's Encrypt certificate fails to renew when I run

```bash
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

I get the following message

```bash
1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.din-pt.no
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.din-pt.no/.well-known/acme-challenge/pW5ACTpIbvnkdSpT-lBkRhfGR8steo_R5Zk-yMwQjOU:
   "<html>
   <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
   <body bgcolor="white">
   <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
   <hr><center>"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

I generated the certificates using

```bash
sudo certbot certonly --webroot --agree-tos --no-eff-email --email kontakt@fossekalltek.no -w /var/www/ptpatrick.no/html/ -d www.din-pt.no -d din-pt.no
```

And HTTPS is working on the site.

My renewal config for let's encrypt

```
renew_before_expiry = 30 days
version = 0.19.0
archive_dir = /etc/letsencrypt/archive/www.din-pt.no
cert = /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.din-pt.no/cert.pem
privkey = /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.din-pt.no/privkey.pem
chain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.din-pt.no/chain.pem
fullchain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.din-pt.no/fullchain.pem

# Options used in the renewal process
[renewalparams]
authenticator = webroot
installer = None
account = c0e77a8463a95263b6940fb41543b596
webroot_path = /var/www/ptpatrick.no/html,
[[webroot_map]]
www.din-pt.no = /var/www/ptpatrick.no/html
din-pt.no = /var/www/ptpatrick.no/html
```

I can post additional logs/settings if you want, but I'm not sure what you guys want.

running Ubuntu 16.04 with Nginx

Thank you for all replies!

My Nginx cnfig for the site

Comment: The 404 response is generated by the HTTP and not HTTPS. Have you granted access to `/.well-known` via HTTP?

Comment: Please don't add _solved_ into the title. When you can, mark you answer as accepted and that will tell others the question is solved. Thank you.

Comment: I can't add my answer as accepted for two days, I thought leaving it solved until then would stop people from wasting time with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer! My first server in my nginx.conf only went to the site without "www." in front of it, also adding "www." as a server name solved the issue.